# Why does NOT exist std::errno while "errno" does?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, errno

In order to make my codes more compliant with C++ style instead of C style, I want to replace `errno` with `std::errno`, and replace `include <errno.h>` with `include <cerrno>`.

To my supprise, these's NO `std::errno` !

As we known, many C things have an C++ equivalent. For expamle:

In a c-source.c, we code often like this:

```
#include <string.h>
print( strerro(1) );
```

In a c++source.cpp, we can do it like this:

```
#include <cstring>
std::cout << std::strerro(1);
```

Why is **NOT** there `std::errno` while `std::strerro` exists?

Comment: [`errno` is a macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno). Naturally, macro names can't be scoped to a namespace.

Comment: Side note: the `stl` tag refers to questions about the **S**tandard **T**emplate **L**ibrary, a hugely influential library from the 1990s that provided the ideological  basis (and no small amount of the implementations) for much of the C++ Standard Library when C++ was standardized in 1998. Few people today use raw STL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To my supprised, these's NO "std::errno"!

That is because, `errno` is a preprocessor macro.  It doesn't live in a namespace(actually it has no concept of namespaces etc). From [errno documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno):

> **errno is a preprocessor macro** used for error indication. It expands to a static(until C++11)thread-local(since C++11) modifiable lvalue of type int.

(emphasis mine)

This means that we can't prepend `errno` with `std::`.